# How do I connect my Android app to a MySQL database on a laptop, PC, or server?

Tags: android, mysql

How do I connect an Android device to a PC, laptop, or server?

I have finished my Android program using Eclipse. I also use a client - server system (I'm using MySQL, not SQLite, to store my database)

when I run my program in emulator, it runs nicely (using CustomHTTPClient with address to connect MySQL is `http://10.0.2.2/android/blablabla.php`)

But, will it be the same code to connect to a MySQL database when I deploy the app onto a real device? if no, what should I do to connect the device to my database(MySQL) in my PC/Laptop/Server? How should I change the code?

I don't use Bluetooth because the distance is too short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your computers IP address. Find this by tpying 'ipconfig' into the command prompt. Look for and use your IPv4 address, it should be similar to:

```
192.168.0.XX/android/blablabla.php
```

Comment: so i just have to change the ip address to my PC/Laptop ip address?
does it work when i connect to my PC/Laptop with ad hoc or connectivy?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure that the Android phone is connected to the same network the PC/Server is in and replace `10.0.2.2` with the ip address of the Server. I assume that you don't have a domain.

Comment: yes i dont have a domain...
so i just have to change the ip address to my PC/Laptop ip address?
does it work when i connect to my PC/Laptop with ad hoc or connectivy?